# How to reshape square numpy matrix into "diamond" of diagonals structure most efficiently

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

Say I have a square `numpy.matrix` like this

```
[['78' '17' '53' '28']
 ['22' '75' '31' '67']
 ['15' '94' '03' '80']
 ['04' '62' '16' '14']]
```

and for my purposes I need a "diamond structure" like this of all of the diagonals in an upwards direction (note that a list of lists is fine for my purpose)

```
 [       ['78'], 
      ['22' '17'],
    ['15' '75' '53'],
  ['04' '94' '31' '28'],
    ['62' '03'  '67'],
       ['16' '80'],
         ['14'],      ]
```

What is the best way to do so?

I can't decide if using some incrementing magic with position accessing is required or some built in way making use of `numpy.diagonal` is possible, which I haven't been able to employ successfully yet.

Comment: That's not an NxN array/matrix any more, unless you're masking the other values, or you actually just want a list of lists of that form. Why do you need this? Could you instead rearrange your indexing to mimic it?

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware it'll no longer be a square matrix/array, a list of lists works fine. I need these diagonals for some list-like operations that depend on the length of each diagonal, which I won't know beforehand (not a simple 4x4 case, more like a ~1000x~1000 case)

Comment: That's easy with looping, I'm eager to see a vectorized/neat solution.

Comment: @timgeb Agreed, yeah with indice looping and the matrix size known it's pretty straightforward just a bit tedious. Seems like there must be a better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

a=np.array([[78, 17, 53, 28],
    [22, 75, 31, 67],
    [15, 94, 03, 80],
    [04, 62, 16, 14]])

[np.diag(a[-1:-a.shape[0]-1:-1,:], i).tolist() for i in range(-a.shape[0]+1,a.shape[0])]
```

outputs [[78], [22, 17], [15, 75, 53], [4, 94, 31, 28], [62, 3, 67], [16, 80], [14]] as requested

it works very fast for 1000x1000 matrix as well

Comment: use ``range`` instead of ``xrange`` since the question is for python3 but otherwise: nice answer!