# map diagonals of 2d numpy array

Tags: numpy

Is there any ufunc that is able to map across diagnals of numpy array?

suppose I have

```
A = array([[1, 7, 5, 0, 5],
           [9, 1, 4, 6, 0],
           [9, 6, 1, 0, 0],
           [2, 5, 0, 0, 0],
           [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

And the aggregation function is `max`

the goal would be

```
B = np.diagnols_ufunc(A, np.max)
  = array([ 1,  -> max([1])
            9,  -> max([9, 7])
            6,  -> max([9, 1, 5])
            6,  -> max([2, 6, 4, 0])
            6,  -> max([1, 5, 1, 6, 5])
            ])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reshape square numpy matrix into "diamond" of diagonals structure most efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35360636/how-to-reshape-square-numpy-matrix-into-diamond-of-diagonals-structure-most-ef)

Comment: No.  Even the limited diagonal functions in `numpy` assume the main diagonal has coordinates `(i, i)` (top left to bottom right).  You'd have to make a custom `numba` function and try to make a custom `ufunc` if that's what you really need.

Comment: > Does this answer your question?   this could be one solution, but then I need to duplicate the data, which might not be efficient than `[np.max(np.diagonal(np.flipr(A), i) for i in range(A.shape[0])]`

Comment: > main diagonal has coordinates. this one can be addressed using `flipr`. but having some kind of map based on diagonals might still not work :(